# Excel formula to redistribute sets of items

Tags: excel, formula

Can something like this be done in Excel?

I have sets which each have a different number of items. For example:

- Set A = A1, A2, A3, A4, A5
- Set B = B1, B2
- Set C = C1, C2, C3

I'd like to distribute the items between all the sets but I have two conditions on the resulting sets:

1. Each set must contain the same total items it started with.
2. Each set must contain none of the original items.

For example:

- Set A = B1, B2, C1, C2, C3
- Set B = A1, A2
- Set C = A3, A4, A5

Each time I do this, I'd like the distribution to be different. The items don't have to be sequenced into each set. They could be distributed randomly as long as the two conditions above are met.

*Edited to add an important factor I forgot initially:*

Each time I do this, I have different numbers of items in each set which I cannot predict in advance. Each time, however, the number of sets remains the same.

*Edited to add my working so far*

I've attempted to have a list of all the items keyed to an index and use VLOOKUP to assign them to the equivalent key for the number of items each set can hold. I can't figure out how to tell Excel to skip any items that are from that set originally.

Comment: The answer to your only question is ***yes***, it can be done in Excel. If you plan on just asking "How can it be done?" then you won't get much of a response. Try to figure out the problem yourself, including searching Google etc and update your question with what you have attempted, instead asking "How can it be done? I've tried x,y,z..."

Comment: Well having spent a few hours today trying "to figure out the problem" myself "including searching Google etc" I was fairly convinced that it was NOT possible in Excel. Therefore, the only thing I needed to know to continue was exactly what you provided. Seeing as you obviously know how to do it but didn't mention it that's just as well!

Answer (score 0):

For Set ***A*** the answer is easy, just list the contents of Sets ***B*** & ***C***.

For Set ***B***:
Place the candidate list in cells **B1** through **B8**:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
C1
C2
C3
```

In cells **C1** through **C8** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

In cells **A1** through **A8** enter:

```
=INDEX(B$1:B$8,MATCH(LARGE(C$1:C$8,ROW()),C$1:C$8,0))
```

[image]

As you see, column **A** is a randomization of the candidate list.  Since Set ***B*** must contain *two* items, just pick **A1** and **A2**.

Use a similar technique for Set ***C***.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to share a possible solution. Unfortunately, the first "easy" step is unfortunately not that easy; I forgot to specify that each time I do this, the number of items in each set will vary. I'll modify my question to reflect this.